# Change value of cell based on condition of cell in large sheet

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has 9 columns and about 8000 rows of data.  I am looking for an easy way to quickly replace all data in column H that is less than 2.5 with the value of 0.  I've written the following VBA and it works, but it is sloooooow and locks up Excel while it runs.  Does anyone have a solution that would work faster?  I appreciate your help!

```vb
Sub ScrubData()
    Dim mls As Range
    Dim cnt

    Sheets("IMPORT HERE").Select
    cnt = Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row
    'MsgBox cnt
    For Each mls In Range("H1:H" & cnt)
        If mls < 2.5 Then mls = 0
    Next mls

End Sub
```

[image: Sample Data in Sheet]

When I run the code, it lags out Excel.  When I broke code execution after about 5 minutes the process had barely crawled through half of the rows.

Comment: Maybe load the values in an array, loop through than and then put the resulting values in the range?

Comment: When I try your code on 8000 rows of data the entire operation only takes 1 second. Do you perhaps have many other formula cells that also have to be updated (because they make reference to cells from column "H")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Evaluate:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With ws.Range("H1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
    .Value = .Worksheet.Evaluate(Replace("IF({rng}<2.5,0,{rng})", "{rng}", .Address))
End With
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!!  Ran in 1 second and did exactly what it was supposed to do!  Amazing, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```vb
Sub ScrubData()
    Dim mls As Range
    Dim cnt, arr, i
    Sheets("IMPORT HERE").Select
    cnt = Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row
    'MsgBox cnt
    Set mls = Range("H1:H" & cnt)
    arr = mls.Value
    For i = 1 To cnt
        If IsNumeric(arr(i, 1)) And arr(i, 1) < 2.5 Then arr(i, 1) = 0
    Next i
    mls.Value = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error but I think the error is related to variable 'j' in your example.  Where would I define 'j'?  Also, thank you for the help!

Comment: This also worked like a charm when I updated the new code, thank you!!